# pyodbc and MYSQL connection

Tags: python, class, database-connection, pyodbc

I am aware a similiar question exists. It has not been marked as answered yet and I tried all suggestions so far. I am also not native speaker, please excuse spelling mistakes.

I have written a small class in python to interact with a SQL Database.
Now I want to be able to connect to either SQL or MYSQL Database with the same functionalities.

It would be perfect for me to just change the connection type in the instance initiation to keep my class maintainable. Else I would need to create a seconde class using for example the mysql.connector, which would result in two classes with nearly the same structure and content.

This is how I tried to use pyodbc so far:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=xyzhbv;'
                      'Database=Test;'
                      'ENCRYPT=yes;'
                      'UID=root;'
                      'PWD=12345;')
```

Please note that I changed all credentials.

What do I need to change to use pyodbc for MySQL?
Is that even possible?

Or

Can I use both libaries within one class without confusing? (they share function names)

Many Thanks for any help.

Have a great day.

Comment: As long as you have a mysql odbc driver installed, you can use pyodbc to connect to a mysql database.

Comment: @Shadow and how do I reffer to in connect()

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-2/

Comment: @Shadow thanks for your help so far, I think I am getting close. I checked my ODBC data source and noticed I was missing MySQL drivers. I installed the 32 bit 5.3 ODBC drivers and they are now listed in the data source. I still cant manage to create a connection. The error says "the driver can not be found". I am using the exact driver names provided in the data source. Any hints?

Comment: @Shadow I noticed my mistakes. I had also have 64 bit data source and the MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver installed. I tried this and it works. Many thanks. You reallly helped me.